# URL Routing with an MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I am making a website that displays a bunch of articles. It is built off a MVC I want to be able to search for articles by day and then by an ID number via url.

If the domain name is website.com, I'm trying to figure out how to make routes so that website.com/yyyymmdd hits a specific controller+method and displays all the articles for that day and website.com/yyyymmdd/111 searches that day's articles for article #111.

The issue I'm having is that all the tutorials for routing within an MVC assume I will specify the controller and method in the URL. They show something like:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
    }
```

If anybody could suggest a way to automatically make "website.com/yyyymmdd/111" use a specified controller and method, that'd be amazing.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Today",
            "{date}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", date = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

I've done this as my route and my method is as follows:

```
    public ActionResult ArticlesByDate(string date, int id)
    {
        if(id > 1)
        {
            return View(Contact());
        }
        else
        {
            return View(About());
        }

    }
```

I hope I am understanding your guys' suggestions, but this is giving me a "Resource can not be found" error when i try to navigate to: "http://localhost:52159/20160908/2"

Comment: Basic search https://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+routing+specify+controller should have given you decent tutorials... or SO posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854483/use-mvc-routing-to-override-controller-name-when-presented-with-specific-action.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1):

One way this can be solved by using the date as a parameter to the action.

Your action would look like

```
public ActionResult Index(string articleDate,string id) ...
```

The your route definition would be something like

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{articleDate}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",articleDate=DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), id = "" });
}
```

Then you can take it from there

Answer (score 1):

Second route for default mvc routing mechanism.

First route is for articles.Controller and action value is static. You can change date and id  values for website.com/20160911/111 , website.com/20160912/112 etc.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Articles",
          url: "{date}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Articles", action = "Info"});

      routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }

   public class ArticleController : Controller {

        public ActionResult Info(string date, int id){

            return View();

        } 
    }
```

---

**you cant redirect two view in an action**. Use one view and partial views within.

for example

Info.cshtml

```
    @if(id > 1)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Contact") 
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.Partial("_About") 
    }
```

Comment: You obviously missing route constraints for date (so wrong once fall back to default), but otherwise exactly what OP is looking for.

Comment: why fall back default i dont understand :( i except that it will route Article controller Info action @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: @SercanTimoçin Thanks for the suggestion!  That seems to be exactly what I need.  However I'm encountering another problem now.  I'm putting my progress in the OP.